# tkinter Add/Edit array using button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to add use add/delete button to edit the values in an array. I am thinking to use the 'index of curselection' to get a index, and then use array.remove the selected value. However, i am getting an index value with a comma.... i tried with strip but comma wont go away.

```
import tkinter as tk
window=tk.Tk()
window.title('TEST')
window.geometry('600x600')
e=tk.Entry(window,show=None)
e.pack()
arr_allDesc = []

def add():
        var=e.get()
        lb.insert('end',var)
        arr_allDesc.append(var)
        e.delete(0,'end')
        print(arr_allDesc)

def delete():
        print(lb.curselection())
        word = str(lb.curselection())
        print(arr_allDesc[arr_allDesc.index(word)])
        #print(word)
        #print(word.strip)
        #select = str(lb.curselection())
        #print(select)
        #arr_allDesc.remove(select)
        #lb.delete(lb.curselection())
        #print(arr_allDesc)

b1=tk.Button(window,text='add',width=15,command=add)
b1.pack() 


b2=tk.Button(window,text='delete',command=delete)
b2.pack()

lb=tk.Listbox(window)
lb.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

i can use add button to create an array as below:
['', '1', '2', '3', '33']

but i am getting '(2,)' when i print out selected index from :aray.print(arr_allDesc[arr_allDesc.index(word)])
which is not in a list.

Please tell me where i did wrong, and how come i am not returning correct index value. I thought i should be getting like this '2', which will match array and remove '2' from array.

Comment: the unprofessional way would be to slice it or index it again

Comment: That's because it is a tuple, not a str, to get the first selection, you could use `lb.curselection()[0]`.Or I recommend you use `lb.index("active")`.

Comment: Since `Listbox` supports multiple selections, so `curselection()` will return a tuple of indexes, even though only one item is selected.  Actually `arr_allDesc` is not necessary, you can get the current item list by calling `lb.get(0, 'end')`.

Comment: lb.index("active") solved my problem.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA: the "active" selection isn't necessarily all of the selected items. It might not even represent something that is selected at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curselection` returns a tuple of indexes, since it's possible to configure the listbox to have more than one selected item. Even if you've configured the `selectmode` to be "single" (or are accepting the default value), it still returns a tuple.

The correct thing to do is either loop over all the items in the current selection, or use indexing to get the first selected index. Since only one item can ever be selected, you can always just use the first item in the returned tuple.

Also, you can use the computed index to get the word straight out of the listbox without needing to use a separate array. Of course, you can use the array if you wish, but that seems to add unnecessary complexity.

```
def delete():
    selection = lb.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        word = lb.get(index)
        print(f"word: '{word}'")
```

Note: using the "active" index isn't guaranteed to be the item that is selected. It represents the selection cursor which can be independent of the selected item.

In the following screenshow, "three" is what you get if you use "active", even though "one" is the selected item:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thx for the clear explain on the active and curselection !

Answer (score 0):

Thx to everyone comments:

I used lb.index("active"), and here are the updated code:

```
def delete():
        selected = arr_allDesc[lb.index("active")]
        print(arr_allDesc[lb.index("active")])
        #Remove from array
        arr_allDesc.remove(selected)
        #Remove from window
        lb.delete(lb.curselection())
```

Comment: You solution does not work if there are duplicate items in the listbox.  For example, if the listbox contains `[1,2,3,1]` and you select the last `1` and click `delete` button.  Then the last `1` of the listbox is removed, but the first `1` in `arr_allDesc` will be deleted instead, not the last one.

Comment: The active selection may not work in all cases. It represents the selection cursor, and that may be different from the actual selection.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, i am now thinking how to deal with duplicate items..You are ahead of me

Comment: You should use `lb.curselection()` instead of `lb.index()`.  For example, `selection = lb.curselection()`, `if selection: index = selection[0]`.  Then use `lb.delete(index)` and `arr_allDesc.pop(index)`.